# How to set parameters on a CI/CD pipeline for Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am currently building multiple pipelines that share the same parameters.
One parent pipeline sends the parameters to the others when it executes them.

When I am setting the file: arm-template-parameters-definition.json, how can I specify that I want to change the parameters only for the parent pipeline?

He is currently detection all parameters with same name and creates more than 250 parameters.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set a different parameter name for the parent pipeline, something prefixing with 'Parent_ParameterName'

In ADF UI, go to Manage *menu* -> *Paremeterization Template* -> provide the variable name in the section   **"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"**:

```
variables": {
        "Parent_ParameterName": {
          "defaultValue": "="
        },
```

publishing the parameterization template will create the parameter only for the parent pipleine i.e. the parameters that matches the 'parent_parameterName'

Answer (score 0):

There's this new Global Parameters feature available since beginning of August.
It can come in handy!

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question; it is better suited as a comment. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but what I typically do is add global parameters and then reference those everywhere (in your case from the pipeline parameters).  Then in your build you can override the global parameters with the values that you want.

So from your 'child' pipelines, you would create a pipeline parameter just like you do today, but the value of that parameter would be the global parameter name like this:

[image]

[image]

Here are some links to references that I used to get this working:

- [Azure Data Factory CI-CD made simple: Building and deploying ARM templates with Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines](https://towardsdatascience.com/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-made-simple-building-and-deploying-your-arm-templates-with-azure-devops-30c30595afa5)
- [ADF Release - Set global params during deployment](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2021/11/adf-snack-set-global-params-during.html)
- [Global parameters in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters)